# Entity Framework Core: bug when inserting?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I searched on the internet and github and couldn't find a solution. I add product image at the same time while adding product.

I noticed something that if I set the `Product Image Id` it doesn't add it to the database. I can't quite understand why this is happening.

```
var result = new Result<Product>();

try
{
    if (entity.Id == Guid.Empty)
        entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    if (entity.InsertDateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
        entity.InsertDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    entity.isDelete = false;
            
    if (entity.ProductImages != null && entity.ProductImages.Count > 0)
    {
        if (entity.ProductImages.Where(x => x.Base64 == null).Count() > 0)
        {
            entity.ProductImages = entity.ProductImages.Where(x => x.Base64 != null).ToList();
        }
            
        foreach (var item in entity.ProductImages)
        {
            // I noticed something that if 
            // I set the Product Image Id it doesn't add it to the database
            if (item.Id == Guid.Empty)
                item.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

            if (item.InsertDateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
                item.InsertDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            var file = item.Base64.Base64DecodePhysicalImage(imageFileLocation + entity.Id.ToString(), item.Id);
            item.ProductId = entity.Id;
            item.PublicURL = file.FullPath;
            item.PhysicalName = file.FileName;
            item.Base64Prefix = file.Base64Prefix;
            item.isActive = true;
            item.isDelete = false;                        
        }
    }

    result.Entity = _dataProvider.Add(entity);
    result.Status = Enums.BLLResultType.Success;
```

After the operations here, the save process is done.

```cs
public class DataAccessTemplate<TRepository, TEntity> : IDataAccesTemplate<TEntity> where TRepository : DbContext, new() where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        using (TRepository Context = new TRepository())
        {
            Context.Attach(entity);
            var state = Context.Entry(entity);
            state.State = EntityState.Added;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return entity;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the base entity class:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; } 
    public bool isDelete { get; set; } 
    public DateTime InsertDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeletedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the `Product` class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StockPiece { get; set; }
    public Enums.StockType StockType { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ProductDetail { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
}
```

This is `ProductImage`:

```
[Serializable]
public class ProductImage:BaseEntity
{
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string PublicURL { get; set; }
    public string PhysicalName { get; set; }
    public string ImageAltValue { get; set; }
    public bool isMainImage { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Base64 { get; set; }
    public string Base64Prefix { get; set; }
    public int SSSS { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. The presence of a try suggests to me you are likely going into the catch.

Comment: It looks like there is no code where you are adding to the product images collection ProductImages, like entity.ProductImages.Add(..). Adding the entity to the collection is required before the Context.SaveChanges() can commit the reference collection record(s).

Comment: There is data in the collection, if you want I can show you with an image @AndrewHalil

Comment: It looks like when you test the item.Id is empty, you then set it to a new Guid, but this does NOT add any new records! If the item.Id is empty, shouldn't you then add a new record with context.Add(item)..?

Comment: Its works for me Thanks man